# How to find the first host contacted by cassandra driver during connection?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-python-driver

Is there a way to find out which node was contacted first during the initial setup by the driver? For example, is there a way to find the host 10.9.58.64 that was contacted?

```
WARNING:cassandra.cluster:Cluster.__init__ called with contact_points specified, but no load_balancing_policy. In the next major version, this will raise an error; please specify a load-balancing policy. (contact_points = ['cassandranode1,;cassandranode2'], lbp = None)
DEBUG:cassandra.cluster:Connecting to cluster, contact points: ['cassandranode1,;cassandranode2']; protocol version: 4
DEBUG:cassandra.io.asyncorereactor:Validated loop dispatch with cassandra.io.asyncorereactor._AsyncorePipeDispatcher
DEBUG:cassandra.pool:Host 10.9.58.64 is now marked up
DEBUG:cassandra.pool:Host 10.9.58.65 is now marked up
DEBUG:cassandra.cluster:[control connection] Opening new connection to 10.9.58.64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after the connection is established you can use the [cluster.get_control_connection_host](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/master/cassandra/cluster.py#L2129) function to get information about host to which so-called control connection is established.  It's used for administrative purposes, such as getting the updates on the status of the nodes in the cluster, etc.  There is more information about control connection in the [documentation of Java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.10/manual/core/control_connection/).